# Linking list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, variables

I have a list in HTML that holds the attributes data-answer and data-sum. The grid is populated with hidden answers. When a hidden answer is highlighted the user uses the sum to work out what the answer is. At the moment when an answer is highlighted the sum is not the correct one linked in the HTML, so the user cannot work it out.

What is wrong with my code, why won't it pair these two attributes up. Is it because I haven't set a variable for answers?

I have this list...

```
<ul style="display:none;" id="answerlist">

    <li data-answer="1" data-sum="4 - 3 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="2" data-sum="7 - 5 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="3" data-sum="1 + 2 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="4" data-sum="1 + 3 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="5" data-sum="4 - 3 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="6" data-sum="10 - 4 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="7" data-sum="4 + 3 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="8" data-sum="2 x 4 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="9" data-sum="4 + 5 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="10" data-sum="1 x 10 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="11" data-sum="10 + 1 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="12" data-sum="2 x 6 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="13" data-sum="9 + 4 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="14" data-sum="2 x 7 ="></li>

    <li data-answer="15" data-sum="11 + 4 ="></li>

  </ul>
```

The answer works fine, but when I go to pull the question into the div - ".sumstyle" it is always the wrong one to the question.

```
var sum = $('#answerlist li[data-answer=' + answer + ']').data('sum');
$('.sumstyle').text(sum);
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am setting the variable for sum?

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZAfVZ/21/

Comment: I don't understand; are you *setting* DOM-element data with `.data`, or are you trying to *retrieve* the `.attr('data-sum')` value? There's also a JS error for me under Chrome; have you checked your console?

Comment: Trying to retrieve the value. But trying to retrieve the correct one linked to the other data in the list @Dave Newton

Comment: That totally doesn't answer my question. If you're trying to *retrieve* data from the `.data("sum")`, where are you setting it? I don't see it. Also, JS error on loading the fiddle because of `sum.hide()`s.

Comment: Could that be my problem then? I need to set it? @David Newton

Comment: You obviously need to set it if you want to retrieve it--but I don't know what it's *supposed* to be. Again: do you mean to retrieve the value of the `data-sum` *attribute*?

Comment: Yes basically I want to retrieve the value of the sum and show it in the div ".sumstyle". It does it at the moment, but it pulls through a random one rather than the one linked to the data-answer attribute highlighted in the grid @David Newton

Comment: Where does the value of the 'answer' variable come from, and is it definitely populated as you expect it to be?

Comment: It is the value in data-answer. They populate the grid just fine, my problem is when one of the answers are highlighted, the sum that helps the user work it out is not the correct one. I need a way to link the two if you get what I mean @SteveWilkes

Comment: I get that the value of the `answer` variable is written into the JQuery selector so JQuery can find the appropriate li element from which to read the `sum` data attribute - I'm wondering if the `answer` variable doesn't contain what it should, which is why JQuery isn't selecting what you want it to.

Comment: How would I overcome this? @SteveWilkes

Comment: Can you debug it and view what the value of the `answer` variable is on that line?

Comment: which one do you mean? @SteveWilkes

Comment: `var sum = $('#answerlist li[data-answer=' + answer + ']').data('sum');` - the `answer` variable being written into the JQuery selector there.

Comment: I need to declare it then don't I. Would I declare it like this.. var answer = $('#answerlist').find('li:data-answer');? @SteveWilkes

Comment: When you say "a hidden answer is highlighted", how does that happen? Does someone mouse over one of the list items?

Comment: No if you look at the fiddle some of the grid is highlighted. This has a number behind that you can see if you press "ctrl+a". You are supposed to work out this number from the sum in the div, and press the blue numbers accordingly. The problem is the sum is never the correct one to get the answer @SteveWilkes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've had a look at the Fiddle, and the reason this:

```
var sum= $('#answerlist li[data-answer="'+answer+'"]').data('sum');
```

...on line 120 isn't finding the li element you want is that the `answer` variable being written into the JQuery selector has no value. This means you're really doing this:

```
var sum= $('#answerlist li[data-answer=""]').data('sum');
```

...which is looking for the li element where the data-answer attribute has no value, which does not exist.

Where is the value of `answer` on that line supposed to come from? There's a local `answer` variable used in the earlier `for / while` loop around line 100 - is that it?

Comment: Ok I see. That is the correct answer on line 100 because it fills the grid with answers. So where do I go from here? @Steve Wilkes

Comment: `answer` is also used in the click handler for `minibutton`, although again it's not been given a value as far as I can see. What's the value in that handler supposed to be / where's it supposed to come from?

Comment: Sorry the minibutton one is supposed to be the only one because the sum and answer are supposed to change when the button is clicked - like a next question button. The one above doesn't matter. @Steve Wilkes

Comment: So do I give answer a value by creating a new variable? @Steve Wilkes

Comment: Bare with me, I'm going to spin the code up and try and figure out what's going on with it  :)

Comment: Ok, I've looked through it running, and I'm not much wiser as to what you're trying to achieve, to be honest. Would you like to give me an email address so I can email you and we can talk about it in more detail?

Comment: Yes please that would be great. Although if you mark my question up I have enough rep to go to chat. @Steve Wilkes

Comment: I'm one of the people who already marked your question up :) I'll email you later today :)

Comment: Ok, I've made a note of your address - you might want to delete that comment so your address isn't picked up spam spiders :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the heads up. I have worked it out now but I am having trouble with the button now http://jsfiddle.net/ZAfVZ/28/ @Steve Wilkes

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is that the attribute `data-sum` is a string and not an integer.
You will need to fetch the attribute and eval the variable in order to get the right sum.

**Update**: Once you get your attribute do

```
var attribute_value = "5 + 7 ="; // assumed attribute value
var solution = attribute_value.substring(0, attribute_value.length -2);
var sum = eval ( solution );
alert(sum);
```

Comment: like this: var answer = eval(sum)? @Thariama

Comment: if 'sum == "4 + 5"' yes, but your attribute consists of '4 + 5 =' - to make it work you would need to strip the '='

Comment: Where in my code would I place it? Also getting rid of the "=" is not a problem, but is there a way around it? @Thariama

Comment: The code in your fiddle is volumenous. Can you explain why you use the attribute data-sum they way you use it?

Comment: It didn't work when I tried it but I may have put it in the wrong place @David Newton

Comment: data-sum is given to give the correct answer. The grid is filled with hidden numbers (data-answer). When they are highlighted the user is supposed to guess the number with the use of data-sum (the sum). At the moment the sum shown in the div ("sumstyle") is the wrong sum for the highlighted hidden answer so it is impossible for the user to get it correct. I basically need to find a way to pull out the correct data-sum and show that in the div @Thariama

Comment: Would it be possible to put it in a fiddle? @Thariama

Comment: But how does this fit into what I have? This just gives an alert that says sum 1. @Thariama

Comment: have a closer look here http://jsfiddle.net/5cCw8/7/ . sum holds the calculated answer which in the first fiddle is "1" (4 - 3)

Comment: So where you have set it to pick the last sum. I need it to pick the sum with the answer highlighted in the grid. So if the number 4 was in the grid. Then the div would display the corresponding sum ie "1+3" @Thariama

Comment: I used "...:last" to pick the last li-element. How do you want to choose the li element?

Comment: I don't want to pick it. When the data-answer is highlighted in the grid, the data-sum in the same <li> should appear automatically. Do you see what I mean? @Thariama

Comment: the data-sum in the same <li> should then appear where? can you mark the specified point of time in your fiddle code?

Comment: Should appear in the div class ".sumstyle" with the lines           var sum = $('#answerlist li[data-answer=' + answer + ']').data('sum');                                      and $('.sumstyle').text(sum);

Comment: will have a closer look tomorrow

Comment: i still need the point of time, can you give me a detailed desciption of where to klick and what to do after the fiddle is loaded in order to specify at what point of time/action you want to display the sum?